# Compile part of code rely on OS in Qt

Tags: qt

I need to figure out the operating system my program is running on during runtime.

I'm using Qt 4.8.1, MinGW. My program shall run a command-line QProcess on Windows or Linux. Now I need a kind of switch to run the different code depending on the operating system. I'm aware of macros like `Q_OS_WIN23`, `Q_OS_LINUX` and etc. But I don't know how to switch the part of code while compiling it, so that depending on OS it ignored irrelevant one? Could you show via snippet?
Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `#ifdefs` in order to figure out in compilation time the operating system:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_MAC
// mac code here
#endif

#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
// linux specific code here
#endif

#ifdef Q_OS_WIN32
// windows code here
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to do it on project level and separate platform specific code in each file. See [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-advanced-usage.html#scopes-and-conditions).

Example:

```
win32 {
    SOURCES += paintwidget_win.cpp
}
```